# Use cbv vIews in other place

Tags: django, django-views

Hello i wrote a simple login view (for example) like it:

```
class SingInView(LoginView):
    template_name = 'account/auth/login.html'
    redirect_authenticated_user = True
    form_class = LoginForm
```

and i wanna know it possible to use it in another place like:

```
SignUpView.as_view(username="example", password="exampleStrong")
```

there are any way??

Comment: No... In fact `.as_view()` will *not* login, it only creates a function that will then hanle requests.

Comment: You furthermore do not need a view for that, you can use a combination of `authenticate` and `login`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and i wanna know it possible to use it in another place like:
>
> ```
> SignUpView.as_view(username="example", password="exampleStrong")
> ```

No, [**`.as_view(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view) does *not* handle a request. it only creates a *function* that will then handle the requests.

You furthermore do *not* need a `SignupView` in the first place for that. You can *create* a user with the [**`.create_user(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user) of the manager of the user model:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

get_user_model().objects.create_user(
    username='example',
    password='exampleStrong'
)
```

You can login a user with a combination of [**`authenticate(…)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate) and [**`login(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login):

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

user = authenticate(username='example', password='exampleStrong')
if user is not None:  # credentials match
    login(request, user)
```

here `request` is thus the request to which you want to bind the login.